# How to check if a BOOL is null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, null

Is there a way I can check to see if a value is NULL/Nil before assigning it to a BOOL?

For example, I have a value in a NSDictionary that can be either TRUE/FALSE/NULL

```
mySTUser.current_user_following = [[results objectForKey:@"current_user_following"]boolValue];
```

When the value is NULL I get the following error

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSNull boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I would like to be able to handle the NULL case.

Comment: Just so you're clear, in Obj-C the following values are equal: 0, NO, NULL, nil. The return value from your dictionary is an NSNull object, not NULL. That's why @ChristopheD is checking against `[NSNull null]`, not NULL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should [check for](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NumbersandValues/Articles/Null.html) `[NSNull null]`:

```
id vUser = [results objectForKey:@"current_user_following"];

if (vUser != [NSNull null]) {
    // do stuff...
}
else {
    // handle the case appropriately...
}
```

Comment: Why call `objectForKey:` twice for the same key?

Comment: You should also check  for nil being returned i.e. no entry for the key exists in the dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

You can test first and assign then conditionally, e.g. something like the following:

```
if (NSValue* val = [results objectForKey:@"current_user_following"]) {
    mySTUser.current_user_following = [val boolValue];
}
```

This:

- avoids calling `objectForKey:` twice by storing the result in a variable
- limits the scope of the variable to the `if` statement
- works because `nil` is is equivalent to 0
- thus only executes the assignment statement if `val` is not `nil`

To additionally check for the value being `NSNull` you'd have to add another test as given by ChristopheD, but i question wether `NSNull` is really needed here - `YES`/`NO` should be sufficient for a description like *"is following"*.
If you have no useful value for a key, you could simply remove it from the dictionary or not insert it in the first place.

Comment: did you mean [val boolValue] rather than [obj boolValue]?

Comment: This doesn't work for me.. (developing for 10.6 targets with ARC).  I get compiler ERRORS stating `Unexpected interface name 'NSValue': expected expression`.  I could remove the assignment of the NSValue inside the check for nil.. but that would sort of defeat the purpose, destroy the brevity of this solution.

Comment: "If you have no useful value for a key...[do] not insert it in the first place." Doh! Of course. Thanks. You just saved me from a "trinary Boolean" situation.