# iOS: Check if boolean is nil (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, boolean

I'm checking in the console if child viewcontroller is loaded:

```
po self.childVC.isViewLoaded 
<nil>
```

My question to you guys is how can check if boolean is nil ?

Comment: You are doing correct. <nil> equivalent to NO if you typecast po (BOOL)self.childVC.isViewLoaded  you will get required result.

Comment: An easy way to convert `<nil>` to NO is simply add a double negative exclamation-command in front. That is, `po !!self.childVC.isViewLoaded`. But as others stated, <nil> == NO in this case so it's not necessary unless it makes you happy

Comment: By typing `po` and printing any `int` containing 0 or `BOOL` containing `NO` will print out `<nil>`. i do not know why lldb is doing this but it's that it does prints `NO` or 0 as `<nil>`.

Answer (score 0):

**LLDB:** As simple as `p self.childVC.isViewLoaded`

**CODE:** `if (self.childVC.isViewLoaded) {//isViewLoaded = YES}`

Answer (score 0):

What about checking like this?

If assume that boolean can be nil then..

```
// Can check nil & NO for isViewLoaded
if (self.childVC.isViewLoaded != NO) {
    //blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Already asked. Please check this [How to check if a BOOL is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760112/how-to-check-if-a-bool-is-null)

```
if (self.childVC.isViewLoaded != [NSNull null]) {
 }
else {
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A `BOOL` is either `YES` or `NO`. There is no other state.

To check if the view is loaded add below code,

```
if (self.childVC.isViewLoaded && self.childVC.view.window) {

    // self.childVC is visible
}
```